# X resources for keboard layout in ~/.Xresources

Tags: keyboard-layout, x-server, x-resources

I am looking to define the keyboard layout in the `~/.Xresources` file.

I tried many variants such as:

```
Xkb.layout: blah,blah  
Xkb*group: ctrl_shift_toggle  
Xkb*option.grp_led: scroll
```

but without success.

Comment: `setkxbmap -option blahblahblah`...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, I know this method. But why can't it be done in `~/.Xresources`? Maybe we just don't know some resource for keyboard?

Comment: That *is* in `~/.Xresources`...

Comment: @Matti Please read the [help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) before doing anything else. You repeatedly misused answers where you can just comment (you always can on your own posts). You proved you could do this under Gilles answer.

Comment: You can't comment because you keep making new anonymous accounts, you're up to three now. Use http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery to recover the one you used to ask the question, and then register it so you can login normally, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

X resources are a way to configure X11 clients that use a toolkit that makes use of them (mostly classical toolkits such as the X toolkit, Motif, etc., excluding modern toolkits such as Gtk and Qt). Although they are loaded into the server, the server just serves as a store, it doesn't parse resources; that's up to each application.

No server settings are configured via X resources. XKB settings are server settings and need to be set via the appropriate utilities (`xkb*` commands).

Comment: Gilles, in any case, I need a way to save keyboard settings in home directory to some file like they are saved to xorg.conf.d files at the present.

Comment: @Matti Add a call to `xkb…` to a script that's executed when you log in: `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsession`, or whatever your desktop environment or window manager uses.

Comment: Your method is not universal and dm-dependent. I need universal method and dont understand why it has not been invented yet. Its inconveniently to configure xserver in many different files with many different utilities if one can to collect xserver settings together in one file in home directory.